# Regular language restricted to smaller alphabet is regular

Tags: induction, automata, regular-language

> Let $L$ be a regular language on some alphabet $\Sigma$, and let $\Sigma_1 \subset \Sigma$ be a smaller alphabet.  Consider $L_1$ the subset of $L$ whose elements are made up only of symbols from $\Sigma_1$, that is
>   $$
> L_1 = L \cap \Sigma_1^*
> $$
>   Show that $L_1$ is also regular.

By intuition, I would say that if L1 is a subset of L and that L is regular, then L1 is also regular, because L1 has less states than L2 and therefore there must be an automata for L1 too. However, I am pretty sure it's not a sufficient proof. Why is that? And how do I develop the intuition to be able to see straight away what I need to do. I can't find any example on the Internet and this is some complex stuff we have here.

Comment: "if L1 is a subset of L and that L is regular, then L1 is also regular" is not true. Every language is a subset of $\Sigma^*$ and $\Sigma^*$ is regular but not every language is regular.

Comment: Hint: You could think of $L_1$ as intersection of two regular languages.

Comment: uh, so how would you prove this?

Comment: Do you know about closure properties of regular languages? That the intersection of two regular languages is also regular?

Answer (score 1):

Hoda is absolutely correct. The way to see that regular languages are closed under intersection is as follows. Let $M(L), M(\Sigma^{*})$ be the DFSMs to accept $L, \Sigma^{*}$ respectively. We can assume DFSM WLOG, as if the machines are not deterministic, we can reduce them to deterministic machines.

So then take an input string and run it on both machines. The string is in their intersection iff both machines accept the string. So you have an FSM accepting the intersection language.

Comment: Why is there an entire FSM accepting only the intersection language if both $M(L)$ and $M(\Sigma^*)$ accept said intersection language?

Comment: You can effectively run $M(L), M(\Sigma^{*})$ in parallel. The precise construction is via a product machine.